# HP server turned off for unknown reasons. I could reach iLO once, but not anymore. What happened?

Tags: power-supply, hp

My HP Server (MicroServer) turned off for some unknown reason.

However I could reach iLO (version4).

With iLO, I could navigate to "Power Management → Server Power page" (or similar, I don't remember correctly).

There was a "Power button" which has an action: "Momentary push".

I clicked on the "Momentary push" action for the power button in iLO, and after that:

- Server stayed powered off (at least it is not asking for IP address).
- iLO also went down (it dropped its IP address).

Now I can't even ping iLO, and from the router I can observe:

- iLO requests an IP (status: "bound").
- Then after 30 seconds it drops the address (status: "offered").
- "Offered" status stays for 10 seconds and then become again (status: "bound").

This 3 steps are keep repeating, and I can't reach or ping iLO.

Can I somehow wake up iLO and then start the server remotely? Note that I don't currently have physical access to it, please don't mention it.

Comment: You might have to accept that physical access is the only solution to the problem. So that’s my only advice for you.

Comment: Might be better asked on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: My wild guess is that your server turned off because its PSU is dying (or some other power supply related issue), and now that you tried to fully power it back on again, it's no longer able to supply enough power to the iLO CPU causing it to keep rebooting, and _somebody_ will need to get physical access to fix it.

Comment: “Note that I don't currently have physical access to it, please don't mention it.” Sorry but it sounds like a physical power issue and remote management via iLO is not possible. You need to get to the physical server itself to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

iLO requires power and network.

If the machine power is entirely offline, including however the iLO is powered, physical access is the only solution. Some iLO have their own power sources for further redundancy and resiliency, and so the iLO not responding indicates a serious power issue with either the server or the entire rack.

Alternatively it could be a network access issue, but your being able to access the router indicates this is a less likely issue.

While you don't want to physically access the device, your wanting something to be so does not mean it will be so. The point of iLO is to reduce the need for physical access, not remove it entirely, and this is clearly a situation where physical presence at the machine is required.